# axios request failed with status 404

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm getting a axios code 404 error on my front end part, here is the code

```
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log(username, password)
      const { data } = await axios.post('/api/users/signin', {
        username,
        password,
      });
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    
  }
```

i'm getting POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/signin 404 (Not Found), axios request failed with status 404. Though I used that api using the rest client in VScode and i'm getting the response that I expect but somehow when i tried to use it on my frontend part im getting the error.

I also used a
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
in my package.json file

Comment: you might want to check the url for the backend

Answer (score 0):

In front end create a file that will return your backend's base url like this:

```
export const baseURL = "http://localhost:3500";
```

then use it in your request. It might not be exactly the solution but this is what I am doing while development.

Answer (score 0):

nvm i already solved this. I just used cors instead. I was just wondering why i'm getting this error but in the previous project i just added a proxy to the package.json in the FE folder and there was no issue..

edit:

I just installed cors to fixed the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).